# unique sums in a finite direct product of sets of integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sumsets

I am an algebraist, and I am wondering if there is a definition for the following:

Let $A_1$, $A_2$, $\ldots, A_n$ be sets of integers (or more generally, subsets of a group $G$). Say that (for the purposes of this question) $A_1\times A_2\cdots\times A_n$ is *special* provided that whenever $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=b_1+b_2\cdots+b_n$ with each $a_i,b_i\in A_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, then $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$, $1\leq i\leq n$.

Is there some terminology for this property? Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: In the case that $A_1,\dotsc,A_n$ are singletons, this notion as known as unique-sum sets (see e.g. http://cmc11.uni-jena.de/proceedings/frisco.pdf).

Comment: @Martin: I suspect there must be something wrong in your statement because if $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are singletons, then also $A_1 \times \ldots \times A_n$ is a singleton, and hence the condition in the question is trivially true. 

Comment: I think Martin is referrring to $B_n[1]$ sets which would -- I think! -- be the case $A_1=A_2=\dots= A_n$

Comment: While what Yemon Choi says is also a pertinent related notion Martin Brandenburg meant something else. Namely, two elements sets (not singletons). The point is that one studies the question when a set (or also multiset) has the property that all the sums of elements of distinct subsets are actually distinct. This corresponds directly to the case that the A_i are of the form {0,a_i} in the present problem. Yet since the present problem is invarinat under shifts this also applies in case each A_i  contains (at most) two elements.   

Comment: A more natural way to state the condition is that $|A_1+\cdots+A_h| = |A_1| \cdots |A_h|$ (the parameter $h$ is more common than $n$ here). These come up in additive combinatorics, but I don't know a name for them. If $A_1= \dots =A_h$, and you don't care about the ordering of the sum (i.e., one can reorder the $b_i$ so that $a_i=b_i$), these are called "Sidon Sets", also $B_h$-sets.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of interesting work using the term "Tiling" (sometimes " [Algebraic Tiling](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algebra_and_Tiling.html?id=QOa-mnX5Y4QC)"), especially when there are two factors although all the factors but one can be combined (I am thinking mainly of Abelian Groups). If $A$ is *any* infinite set of integers which increases quickly enough [then](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/i54/i54.pdf) there is a $B$ with $A \oplus B= \mathbb{Z}.$  For $A \oplus B=\mathbb{Z}$ with $A$ finite, there are [results and open questions](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CO/9802122), cyclotomic polynomials are a useful tool  For $A \oplus B= \mathbb{N}$ (bases for the positive integers) both $A$ and $B$ are [highly structured](http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/freearticles/597531.pdf). Evidently there are connections to [Musical Canons](http://people.sju.edu/~rhall/Rhythms/AsymmetricRhythms/canons.pdf).

There have uses of non-abelian factorizations for [cryptography](http://brain.math.fau.edu/spyros/spyros/prints/tatras.pdf).

There are better and other references but that gives a few entry points